# xdebug - ignoring specific urls/files

Tags: ajax, debugging, vim, xdebug

I have a site with a lot of ajax going on, some calls are very frequent, which makes it impossible to catch the actual call I want in the debugger.
Any idea how to make xdebug ignore those calls?
Or may be somehow making it stop only on breakpoints.

(using vim as a debugclient if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... interesting b/c I always have to digg out the AJAX-Request-URLs aided by Firebug to explicitely start an XDebug-session for those. In my experience those AJAX-calls get ignored.

Could it be that xdebug.remote_autostart is set to 1/On in your config-file. B/c then an XDebug-session is triggered for any request.

Best regards

Raffael

Comment: Yes it's set to on, but as far as I understood when you pass the (whatever) argument in the url it's on for an hour after that anyway... So what's the difference?

Comment: Well, I'd say have a look at the XDebug-documentation then; xdebug.org

Comment: Just trying to work this out myself now, seems to use cookie after the first request, so subsequent ajax calls etc all send that cookie. Must be a way to just debug the main URL/request though. I can't disable cookies as I need it for the web app to work.